# Jquery droppable get multiple draggable id

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to get multiple dragged ids when i dropped to the certain div. `$(ui.draggable).attr('id');` only gets 1st id.

```
  Drag  <ul id="demo" > 
         <li id="1" ></li>
         <li id="2" ></li>
        <li id="3" ></li>
        </ul>

         <div class="drop"> drop here!! </div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".drop").droppable({ 
                drop: function(event, ui) {

  var m_id = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');// only gets 1st id


      // i need to get multiple dragged id 

            1,2,3..     

            }       
            });
```

Please help me out!! Thnks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var m_id = [];
$.each($(ui.draggable), function(i,e) {
   m_id.push(e.id);
});

//gives array with all ID's, could be joined with join()
//for comma seperated list
```

Comment: Still its printing 1st id. Please  help me out sir >>>    var m_id = [];
$.each($(ui.draggable), function(i,e) {
   m_id.push(e.id);  
   var newText =m_id.join(", ");
alert(newText);
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").draggable({ revert: true });

$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    alert(id);
}
});
```